# How can I change the text and image urls in a figma design using the figma API?

Tags: figma, figma-api

I want to be able to dynamically change the text and images in a figma design file, preferably using a JSON to contain the text/image urls. Is this possible with figma api or the figma file?

Comment: Figma's APIs are well documented. Have you reviewed the [documentation](https://www.figma.com/developers)?

Comment: Yes, I reviewed the docs. I don't see a place where i can change the image url in the REST API.  
I could be overlooking this by not searching the right terms. If you know the answer, can you at least tell me if it's possible or tell me the right terms to look up?

Comment: @tommychheng By FigmaAPI are we talking about the REST API? Or all the global API's that includes the plugin API as well?

Comment: I'm fairly new to Figma APIs, i checked the REST documentation page. Does this global / plugin API system allow to make figma files programmatically with new image media / text?

Answer (score 3):

With the API you can't. There are only GET endpoints to nodes and files

[image: There are only GET endpoints to nodes and files]

Maybe you can do it with the [plugin infrastructure](https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/intro/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the plugin api!
dittos uses the plugin API to change the content inside a figma file:
'Using Figma's REST API and their plugin API, we'd be able to allow our users to work in web app or the Figma file, without worrying about changes getting out-of-sync or content getting outdated'
https://www.dittowords.com/blog/building-dittos-figma-plugin